# How to display form values as a preview before submitting into database?

Tags: php, html

in my code its directly saving the values into database but I want to show **preview page for Textfield values** and then after I want to submit the details into Database.How to do that?
    please guide me

```
  <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
      $name=$_POST['name'];
      $course=$_POST['course'];   

       $query="insert into student_tbl(`name`,`course`) values('$name','$course')";
        if ($conn->query($query) === TRUE){
           header("location: home.php");
         }
       else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        }
        $conn->close();  
       }
    ?>
```

This is simple form where am trying with only two values

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.png">
</head>

<body>
    <form action="" method="POST" id="myform" class="mform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <label for="name">name:&nbsp;</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="name" name="course" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <label for="course">Course:&nbsp;</label>
            <select name="course" id="course">
                <option value="" disabled>select users</option>
                <option value="Computer">Computer</option>
                <option value="Physics">Physics</option>
                <option value="Chemistry">Chemistry</option>
                <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <input class="form-control" type="submit" value="Preview" />
            <input class="form-control" type="submit" formaction="formdata.php" value="Cancel" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use your first code snippet and add a boolean which switches it's value to `true` after the method is called. When you submit successfully you can set it to `false` again.

```
$confirm = true;

if($confirm) {
    //Show confirmation html
} else {
    //Query Form values (e.g. database)
    $confirm = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First Save the value in session variable like

```
$_SESSION['name']=$_POST['name'];
$_SESSION['course']=$_POST['course'];
```

Then in Next print SESSION value

```
echo $_SESSION['name'];
echo $_SESSION['course'];
```

Then in this page fire insert query

```
$name=$_SESSION['name'];
$course=$_SESSION['course'];   

   $query="insert into student_tbl(`name`,`course`) values('$name','$course')";
```